# Internal Server Error while using Frontpage Server Extension on SharePoint2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, internal-server-error, frontpage-extensions

I am working on a Proof of concept where I am trying to use Frontpage server Extension - RPC protocol to upload the files in sharepoint document library using "/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll". I am using following URL to upload bytes to SharePoint Document library.

```
http://SPServer/Site/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll?method={0}&service_name=put+document&document=[document_name=<Encoded document path>;meta_info=[]]&put_option=overwrite,migrationsemantics&keep_checked_out=false&comment=
```

The same code works on one sharepoint environment but not on other. 
I am getting Internal Server Error (500) exactly when i try to execute the webrequest.GetResponse for the url given above.

Any pointers will be greatly appretiated.

Regards,

Indra

Comment: This is probably better suited to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136504/internal-server-error-while-using-frontpage-server-extension-on-sharepoint2013